# How can I tell if I have root access to my server?

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, migration

I have a website hosted in a web hosting service called [Hosting24](http://www.hosting24.com/). I'd like to migrate to [Liquidweb](http://www.liquidweb.com/), and the guys at Liquidweb say they will handle the whole migration process for me which is good because I wouldn't know where to start and I'd most likely mess something up.

I just talked to a customer support guy and he says they can do it as long as I have root access. And he couldn't tell me how can I tell whether I have root access or not. Any idea how can I figure this out? Also, did you every use one of these migration services? Is there anything the sales guy is not telling me?

Comment: Please tell the hosting plan you are currently using.<br/>
If you have bought the shared hosting then you won't have root access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the web host you currently use shows that they only offer 2 hosting packages that are both less than $10/month. This is pretty much guaranteed to be shared hosting as VPS starts at at least $20/month on the extreme low end. So that means you probably don't have root access.

That said, there's no reason the other host would need root access to help you migrate your site. He probably just means you need full access to the master account of your current web hosting subscription. So as long as you have access to the billing account and provide them with the login info you use to log into your current web host's control panel, that should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for answering!. The guy told me about the root thing when I asked him whether they'll be able to migrate the _whole_ thing including emails accounts and emails themselves, databases, domain name, etc... Do you think all this would be possible without root access?

Comment: @jsoldi: Yes, he should be able to migrate all of that without root access. It might take a little more time to migrate the email accounts without root access, but it's still doable. At most, he could simply ask the current web host to export the email data for him.

Answer (score 1):

To check if you have root access, you can connect to your machine using ssh and type :

> root@server:~# whoami  root

You may not need to have root access...

Do you have databases, users, mail files to migrate ?
You basically just have flat files on the server ? You just need ftp

Mail accounts ? You just need imap access and drag and drop between servers using your mail client. (perfect time to switch to google apps for your domain)

Can you specify what you need to transfer ?

Comment: Everything. Databases, email accounts, emails, web pages, domains and probably some stuff I'm forgetting. Regarding your code above, where do am I supposed to enter that? And do am I supposed to change `root@server` for something else or just type it literally? OK I just found out what SSH is. I'll need to look into that.